# jQuery - Bind swipes but keep touchmove functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe-gesture, touch-event

I'm using this: http://pastebin.com/PQYqfeND to bind swipeLeft & swipeRight. I need it to be on a post body, but the problem is that when I bind it, it removes touching completely - meaning I can't drag down/up.

What can I do to allow for touchmove up/down but still bind swipeleft/right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I go, answering my own Q again. I've done days of research, but didn't know what to look for I guess.

The answer is to not use the code above and adapt this: http://pastebin.com/daGupDeL

Usage is pretty easy, I'm able to bind multiple swipes (up to 2, I suppose) on large content, and then a slideshow, w/o them interfering + able to use touchmove/drag on the swipeable content.